# Query based on spark dataframe cell value

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, databricks

I want to run many queries on a table leveraging the Spark framework with python by running them in parallel rather than in sequence.

When I run queries with a for loop, it performs very slowly as (I believe) it's not able to break the job in parallel.  For example:

```
for fieldName in fieldList:
   result = spark.sql("select cast({0} as string) as value, 
      count({0}) as FREQ 
      from {1} group by {0} order by FREQ desc limit 5".format(fieldName, tableName))
```

I tried to make a dataframe with a column called 'queryStr' to hold the query, then have a 'RESULTS' column to hold the results with a command:

```
inputDF = inputDF.withColumn('RESULTS', queryUDF(inputDF.queryStr))
```

The UDF reads:

```
resultSchema = ArrayType(StructType([
  StructField('VALUE', StringType(), True),
  StructField('FREQ',IntegerType(), True)
]), True)
queryUDF = udf(lambda queryStr: spark.sql(queryStr).collect(), resultSchema
```

I'm using spark version 2.4.0.

My error is:

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

So, how do I run these queries in parallel?  Or, is there a better way for me to iterate through a large number of queries?

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue as: [Trying to execute a spark sql query from a UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912359/trying-to-execute-a-spark-sql-query-from-a-udf)

In short, cannot perform SQL queries within a UDF.